# Save documents on OneDrive using Microsoft Graph API and MSAL auth

Tags: azure-active-directory, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

An application my colleague and I are working on generates some PDF-files and streams the result back to the client. This MVC application is only targetted for one specific customer.

The idea is to centralize the export of the PDF-files to OneDrive (for Business) , so that the customer can view the document any time, any place, on any device.

Is it possible to use Microsoft Graph API in combination with msal authentication (v2.0 endpoint) to accomplish this?
Could we consider OneDrive for Business as a "central storage" solution
for small businesses?

Thank you for any advice.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v2 authentication endpoint does not currently support app-only scopes which authenticated without UI-interaction. You can get the access token and refresh token using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) by login in the Azure AD. Then you can use the access token and refresh token whiteout users interacted.

The refresh tokens are valid for 14 days, and with continuous use, they can be valid up to 90 days. After 90 days, users will be asked to re-authenticate.

Here is an sample that for your reference to upload the PDF to OneDrive for bushiness:

```
   public static void CreateItem(string accessToken)
    {
        string itemCreateUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children";
        string itemData = "{\"name\":\"book2.pdf\",\"file\":{}}";
        var itemCreatedResult = RESTRequsetHelper.RESTRequsetHelper.PostAsync(itemCreateUri, itemData, accessToken).Result;
        DriveItem item = new DriveItem(itemCreatedResult);

        string itemUploadUri= $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item.Id}/content";

        System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\users\user1\desktop\book1.pdf",System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);
        var uploadResult= RESTRequsetHelper.RESTRequsetHelper.SendHttpRequest(HttpVerb.PUT, itemUploadUri, streamContent, accessToken).Result;

        fs.Close();

    }

  public static async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, string jsonBody, string accessToken)
    {
        return await SendHttpRequest(HttpVerb.POST, uri, jsonBody, accessToken);
    }

   private static async Task<string> SendHttpRequest(HttpVerb ver, string uri, string jsonBody, string accessToken)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", $"{accessToken}");
        var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonBody,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

        if (ver == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            return await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent).ContinueWith<string>((response) =>
           {
               return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
           });
        }
        else
        {
            return await client.PutAsync(uri, stringContent).ContinueWith<string>((response) =>
            {
                return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            });
        }

    }

    public static async Task<string> SendHttpRequest(HttpVerb ver, string uri, StreamContent steamBody, string accessToken)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", $"{accessToken}");

        if (ver == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            return await client.PostAsync(uri, steamBody).ContinueWith<string>((response) =>
            {
                return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return await client.PutAsync(uri, steamBody).ContinueWith<string>((response) =>
            {
                return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Really need to have app-only scopes which authenticated without UI-interaction.

hopefully the team can bring this feature

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using some variant of a C# application (ASP.NET, UWP, Xamarin). In any of these cases, what you are attempting to do it definitely possible.

Both the [UWP Snippets sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-sample) and the [Xamarin Snippets sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/xamarin-csharp-snippets-sample) demonstrate authentication using MSAL combined with various Microsoft Graph calls using the Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET. Both also have examples for uploading, downloading, updating, and other operations on OneDrive.

If you are using a different platform / language other than .NET, MSAL wouldn't apply but there [many other samples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=sample) on Github for you to check out. Several of them demonstrate the use of the v2.0 authentication endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response Robert.

The PDF documents are generated on the Web API C# part and they need to be uploaded to OneDrive using MSAL & Graph API. 
(I assume on the articles that these technologies are the best choice at this moment.)

These actions should happen without UI-interaction.

Best regards,
Jens

Comment: MSAL will need to run through the authentication UI flow and give permissions to your app via a user. Assuming you maintain the refresh token you get back, you can continue to refresh your access token for quite a while.

The calls to the graph require no user interaction once you have an access token.


There are ways to use [client credentials flow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service/) to authenticate to the graph from a daemon / service without user flow. You may want to look at that as well.